# Exec Powershell Hyper-V CMD in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I have problem trying to use the Get-VM command of the Hyper-V to get the status of the vms,I trying to use powershell via c#.

I search multiple topics,have alredy executionpolicy to unrestricted in 32 and 64 bits powershell, and the hyperv module is in both folders of the powershell(in the /modules folder in syswow32 powershell and in the normal) im runing windows 8.1.
In both powershell the commands works witouht need to import nothing, so I'm really in a loss.

The response when I execute is: Error in script : The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
private void RunScript(string scriptText)
{
   // create Powershell runspace
    InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    initial.ImportPSModule(new[] { "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\Hyper-V\\Hyper-V.psd1", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules\\Hyper-V\\Hyper-V.psd1" });
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-VM");

    // add an extra command to transform the script
    // output objects into nicely formatted strings

    // remove this line to get the actual objects
    // that the script returns. For example, the script

    // "Get-Process" returns a collection
    // of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    textBoxOutput.Text+= stringBuilder.ToString();
    runspace.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved,changed from 3.5 to .net 4.5 and do the trick,(any .net 4+ should work)seems that Hyperv module is not supported on that version,or something like that and was causing the trouble and not loading the modules.